# Could not Create Services for JIRA

Tags: java, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I  would like to create a service for JIRA. I'm using atlassian-plugin-sdk-3.8.

I write program in java for that service.. When i'm importing the atlassian api

```
import com.atlassian.jira.project.ProjectManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager;
ProjectManager pm = ComponentManager.getInstance().getProjectCategories();
```

After i write it, i use atlas-package command.

But here it shows BUILD-FAILURE

```
[INFO] Compilation failure

F:\services\module\src\main\java\com\first\module\MyPlugin.java:[9,25] cannot fi
nd symbol

could not parse error message:   symbol:   class ComponentManager
  location: package com.atlassian.jira
F:\services\module\src\main\java\com\first\module\MyPlugin.java:20: cannot find
symbol
ProjectManager pm = ComponentManager.getInstance().getProjectCategories();
                    ^
```

Whats the reason?

Comment: Have a look into the official [documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Appendix+A+-+Extending+JIRA).

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following depending on your `jira api` version:

```
ProjectManager pm = ComponentManager.getInstance().getProjectManager();

ProjectManager pm = ComponentAccessor.getProjectManager();
```

For more details look at [JIRA api](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Add dependecies to your pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
    <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jira.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```